# How to make a non-displayed input or its label `keyboard tab stoppable`?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, tabstop

To have a customized `input file`, I've made it hidden by:

```
 input[type="file"]{display:none;}
```

and have put a background for its `label`:

```
 label.uploadfilelabel {background-image:url(../image.jpg);}
```

This approach works fine, But it has introduced another problem: Keyboard tab does not stop on this button and its label. I tried using `tabindex="0"` with no result. Is there any way to stop keyboard tab on this hidden button?

Of course, I prefer a pure `CSS` solution, but a javascript solution (without `jQuery`) is also acceptable.

Thanks for sharing

UPDATE: Here is a [fiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/fxh34nyf/). I tested, It works in IE and FireFox but not in Chrome

Comment: with display:none, you are not hidden any element, you are putting the element completely out of the web flow. Try visibility:hidden insteed

Comment: @Alvaro I replaced `display:none;` with `visibility:hidden;` and `visibility:collapse;`. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: A fiddle showing the problems may help us finding a solution (if any)

Comment: @Alvaro Here I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxh34nyf/). It works in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You should try this. It works, but keep in mind it is html5.

```
<input type="file" tabindex="-1">
```